# is there a masters degree in Mobile development like android?

Tags: android

it's not a programming question, but programmers related.

if yes, please guide me to some colleges that have that program.
thanks.

Comment: I certainly hope not. And if there is, be very, very suspicious.

Comment: Certificate.. maybe, but master degree !!!!

Comment: I don't see any problem with such specialization, phones are THE most important device nowadays.

Comment: If there would be any, I'll tried to attend, it is more practical and useful than current Masers with theoretical old contents.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As with the other mobile app development platforms, these fields are *typically* too new for degree programs. You will find other educational opportunities out there, there are classes, books, screencasts in iPhone, PalmOS, Android, Blackberry, etc. development just a google away.

There *are* things like the Graduate degree program [Tisch Interactive Telecommunications Program](http://itp.nyu.edu/sigs/program/) at NYU. The work produced there often has [a mobile spin to it](http://itp.nyu.edu/sigs/mobile/category/featured/).

Here's a class syllabus for [Mobile Me(dia)](http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/syllabus.html), for example, though I'm not sure if that class is specifically an ITP one.

In California, you could look to [Center for Research in Computing and the Arts](http://crca.ucsd.edu/), which I think has somewhat similar aims.

To look for other schools doing Android development courses, you could try a search like: [`"android development" site:.edu`](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22android+development%22+site:.edu). Fair number of folks with *classes* at least: University of California, Carnegie Mellon, Columbia, Temple University, and many others.

**Update**

A bit of googling finds [Master's Degree Programme in Mobile Technology and Business](https://www.jyu.fi/it/en/motebu) at  [University of Jyväskylä](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Jyv%C3%A4skyl%C3%A4) in Finland, which seems rather closely related to, if not exactly an answer to your question.

Answer (score 14):

That's just too specific. You can do a Masters degree in C.S. and take mobile programming classes and do your Masters project or thesis on mobile programming and even work with an adviser and do some research at the Masters level.

Answer (score 4):

I have found this erasmus mundus programme:

[Master's Programme in Security and Mobile Computing](http://nordsecmob.tkk.fi/).

It is the closest i have found so far. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't get a master's in Mobile development.

Many colleges do have a Software Engineering program, and those that don't will usually at least offer a Computer Science program. Either of these will help get you into development. Of course, the Android platform is open source, so if you want to start learning on your own you can grab a compiler and the SDK and start there.

Comment: I second this. What you want is to do is a master in software engineering and then choose to specialise in mobile development.

Answer (score 3):

For developing software and especially mobile applications on platforms like Android or iPhone you most likely won't need any degree at all. The documentation and other resources out there on the Internet are a great way to teach it yourself.

At universities you will learn more about the theoretical aspects and concepts of Computer Science, but it's unlikely that you learn how to program. You will of course have some introduction classes to programming, but *"learning"* programming is more a matter of experience and practice.

**Conclusion:** a degree might be useful, but for sure not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

San Diego State University offers an [Advanced Certificate in Web and Mobile Applications Development](http://www.ces.sdsu.edu/Pages/Engine.aspx?id=752&TermProgramId=5982).

The Certificate in Web and Mobile Applications Development provides students with the specialized knowledge that is important in the development of Web and mobile computer applications. Students will study and gain experience with the languages and frameworks that are most commonly used in developing these applications, with the design of user interfaces and software systems, and with associated topics such as networking, hosting infrastructure, and security. They will also learn the fundamental principles on which these topics are based, so that they will be prepared for the new technologies that are constantly being developed.

This is an advanced academic certificate at the postbaccalaureate level. The admission requirement is a Bachelor's degree in Computer Science or a closely related field. Individuals with an equivalent knowledge of the background materials through work or self-study may be accepted into this program at the discretion of the program director. Courses are a blend of face-to-face and online.

The certificate requires completion of at least four courses (12 units). With the approval of the graduate adviser, the courses taken in this certificate program may be applied toward the Master's degree in Computer Science.

For more information, contact the Department of Computer Science www.cs.sdsu.edu.

Answer (score 1):

Online BS in Mobile Development at a very awesome school...
http://online.fullsail.edu/degrees/mobile-development-bachelors

Answer (score 0):

I'm attending a Postgraduate Course in Software Development for Mobile Devices at Universidad de Alicante(Spain). The is another one in Universidad Politécnica de Valencia (also Spain). They aren't a Master Degree, but are the Postgraduate Course solution. I don't know where you are, but if you can, but the one I'm attending is very recommended.